# KDE Console/Yakuake uses the clipboard improperly

Tags: kde, clipboard, linux-terminal

I'm using KDE Plasma and Yakuake Version 19.12.2.
As I frequently copy and paste from the terminal I use the "Copy on Select" which *works*.

If I select something from the Console and immediately paste it the **previous** object in my clipboard will be pasted. (I see that in Klipper)
Strangely the last - and therefore current - value in the clipboard is the just selected text. But if I want to use the desired text I am required to manually click it.

From my assumption this has to do with the secondary buffer, but I struggle to come to a proper conclusion what causes this weird behaviour.